# How to Prevent Sitecore EXM newsletters from transforming links to RedirectUrlPage.aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, sitecore8

I want to prevent certain links in emails sent by Sitecore EXM from being converted to ".../sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx...".  Specifically, I don't want our image src URLs, such as "https://www.towerswatson.com/assets/image/mailings/wtw_footer_linkedin_blk.jpg", to be converted to any other URL that in turn prevents the image from showing up in the email.

After looking at https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/10/t/5173#pi214filter=all&pi214scroll=false , I basically realized that the below setting in my Sitecore.EmailExperience.Core.config is what controls urls in EXM emails being converted to “…/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx…” :

```
<processor type="Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.GenerateLink.Hyperlink.GenerateHyperlink, Sitecore.EmailCampaign" >
    <RedirectPagePath>/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx</RedirectPagePath>
    <UrlQueryKey ref="settings/setting[@name='QueryStringKey.RedirectUrl']/@value" />
</processor>
```

What I did was in my own Sitecore.EmailExperience.Core.Custom.config , I created an alternative processor that will be called instead so I can somehow manipulate its code to not convert my image src URLs to “…/sitecore/RedirectUrlPage.aspx…”:

```
<modifyHyperlink>
    <processor type="TowersWatson.Custom.EXM.GenerateHyperlink, TowersWatson.Custom" singleInstance="true" patch:instead="processor[@type='Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.GenerateLink.Hyperlink.GenerateHyperlink, Sitecore.EmailCampaign']">
    </processor>
</modifyHyperlink>
```

Here's the code in my GenerateHyperlink class (which is exactly the code in original Sitecore.Modules.EmailCampaign.Core.Pipelines.GenerateLink.Hyperlink.GenerateHyperlink class, which I decompiled and now want to manipulate):

```
public class GenerateHyperlink : GenerateLinkProcessor
{
    public string RedirectPagePath { get; set; }

    public string UrlQueryKey { get; set; }

    public GenerateHyperlink()
    {
        this.UrlQueryKey = "ec_url";
    }

    public override void Process(GenerateLinkPipelineArgs args)
    {
        Assert.IsNotNull((object)args, "Arguments can't be null");
        Assert.IsNotNull((object)args.Url, "Url can't be null");

        if (args.PreviewMode)
            return;

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        args.QueryString[this.UrlQueryKey] = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(args.Url);
        stringBuilder.Append(args.MailMessage.ManagerRoot.Settings.BaseURL);
        stringBuilder.Append(this.RedirectPagePath);

        if (args.QueryString.Count > 0)
        {
            string str = NameValueCollectionExtensions.ToQueryString(args.QueryString, true);
            stringBuilder.Append(str);
        }

        args.GeneratedUrl = stringBuilder.ToString();
    }
}
```

Any idea how I should change the code above to prevent it from manipulating any of the image src URLs?  I'm guessing there's a certain case (if-condition) that should prevent certain lines from executing, or certain logic to execute instead.  I have tried 30 things and nothing has worked.  Thanks!